# What does the "but" mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning, american-english

What does this but mean in this sentence? I doesn't quite seem like it's contrasting anything here.

> The news was shocking, **but** most people realized that they knew little about what a tsunami was, and what caused one of nature's deadliest disaster.

Source: This is from an article that I've been using in class
*What Causes a Tsunami*; SEED (2007) The Earth - a living planet

Comment: So what? In conversational English, people throw *buts* in in every single sentence they say.

Comment: @CookieMonster '_but_' why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can assume that the people, mentioned in your context, knew very less about how deadly a tsunami can be. On reading/ watching/ listening to the news, they understood that their knowledge about a monster wave is very limited. Now, they know how powerful a tsunami can be and what an impact it can create on all things, living and non-living.

The news, although terrifying, gave people a realization that they knew very little about tsunamis. The outcome was definitely bad and disastrous, but the '*people*' had their eyes open to the fact they didn't know much about what a tsunami was, or how it is perhaps, on of the deadliest force of nature.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without more context. Varun may be correct that the "but" implies that there was at least one good outcome from a horrible event.

Another possible implication is that the news was shocking, but the only reason people were shocked was because they were ignorant.